# Inconsistent time format using Qt Locale?

Tags: qt, time, format, qml, locale

I have two Qt based apps that in many ways are nearly identical in the way they are set up. They both display various dates and times using localization, and they both call `QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::Norwegian, QLocale::Norway))` (or various other languages) during startup, but for the same locale set (Norway / Norwegian), the following line gives to different formats in the two apps:

```
someDate.toLocaleTimeString(Qt.locale(), Locale.ShortFormat)
```

With this line, I get `16:32` in one app, and `16.32` in the other (`.` or `:`). And this line:

```
Qt.locale().timeFormat(Locale.ShortFormat)
```

returns `HH:mm` in one, and `HH.mm` in the other.

I can't find any difference in the way the locale is set or used in the two apps, and I have verified that both apps have the same locale set. Does anyone have any idea as to why I get two different formats?

Comment: I struggled a bit to understand how this [QLocale](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html) works. AFAIK about `locale`, you have a general language setting, and you have additional facets (like e.g. your time format aka. `LC_TIME`) which might be overridden. Assuming, it's not an interfering OS setting, one of your applications might override this (and you just missed this).